# No BI Templates after installing SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I had Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 installed then I installed SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2015.  When I open VS 2015 I do not see any of the Business Intelligence Templates that would let me create SSIS and SSRS projects.

[image]

I installed SSDT from this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

On that page it states...

> Alternatively, you can run SSDT Setup on a computer that has an
>   existing, full product installation of Visual Studio. When you install
>   SSDT on a computer that already has Visual Studio, SSDT Setup adds
>   just the SQL Server-related templates to your existing installation.
>   Post-install, the only visible difference will be the availability of
>   new SQL project templates in the New Project dialog box.

So I would expect to see the templates so I can create a SSIS or SSRS project but they are not showing up. Any ideas on how I can get the BI templates to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure that you select the download labeled "Download the Latest SSDT Preview for Visual Studio 2015".  Only the SSDT Preview contains the BI tools.  If you don't see checkbox options for SSIS, SSRS and SSAS in the installer menu, it's not the Preview installer.

Comment: I didn't read the fine print on that page well enough.  For some reason I was thinking the preview version was for SQL Server 2016 and I'm looking to do SSIS on SQL Server 2014.  The Preview version is the answer to getting the templates installed.